# Сравнение и удаление элементов массивов при помощи алгоритмов

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дано три массива, надо первый сравнить с двумя другими и вывести элементы, которые отсутствуют в двух других.

На вход поступают размеры массива и состав:

6

0 5 7 8 9 11

5

1 2 3 4 5

3

3 6 7

должен быть ответ

0 8 9 11

Работающее решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<short> vSh;

short read_item(){
    short item;
    std::cin >> item;
    return item;
}

vSh read_vector(short n){
    cin >> n;
    vSh v(n);
    generate_n(v.begin(), n, read_item);
    return v;
}

int main(){
    short n, m, k;
    vSh v1, v2, v3, dif;

    // Заполняю контейнеры.
    v1 = read_vector(n);
    v2 = read_vector(m);
    v3 = read_vector(k);

    // Объединяю, добавлением во второй контейнер третий.
    copy(v3.begin(), v3.end(), back_inserter(v2));

    //Сортирую получившийся объединённый контейнер.
    sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    //Удаляю в нем повторяющиеся элементы.
    auto it = unique(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    v2.erase(it, v2.end());

    //Сортирую первый контейнер.
    sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());

    //Произвожу "вычитание" из первого контейнера элементы, которые есть в 
    //объединённом.
    set_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                   inserter(dif, dif.begin()));

    //Произвожу вывод элементов через пробел.
    copy(dif.begin(), dif.end(), ostream_iterator<short>(cout, " "));


    return 0;
}
```

Огромное вам спасибо за то что вы своими примерами и замечаниями помогли разобраться в порядке применения алгоритмов!!!

Comment: Без сортировки контейнеров применение стандартных алгоритмов будет не эффективным. И у вас нет массивов, а есть вектора. Может быть лучше использовать std;:multiset?

Comment: Это я могу добавить.

Comment: можете использовать `std::set` если не хотите особо напрягаться

Comment: Конечно, хорошо бы попроще. Разбираюсь, всё работают, но как, пока не до конца понимаю, разбираюсь со сложными конструкциями. Половину алгоритма понимаю, половину нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Минусы**: не учитывает повторений, массивы должны быть отсортированы.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using vector_t = std::vector<int>;

int main()
{
    vector_t vec_f = { 0, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11 };
    vector_t vec_s = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector_t vec_t = { 3, 6, 7 };

    std::move(vec_t.begin(), vec_t.end(), std::back_inserter(vec_s));

    vector_t diff;
    auto it = std::set_difference(vec_f.cbegin(), vec_f.cend(),
        vec_s.cbegin(), vec_s.cend(),
        std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));

    for (const auto& val : diff)
        std::cout << val << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В исходных условиях задания нет ссылки на то, что данные вводятся в сортированном порядке, и что сами вектора можно изменять.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow,  спасибо, сейчас поправлю.

Answer (score 2):

Если контейнеры не сортированы, то придется выполнять последовательный поиск элементов первого контейнера в других двух контейнерах.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как в этом случае можно использовать стандартные алгоритмы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 0, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> v3 = { 3, 6, 7 };

    std::cout << "v1: ";
    std::copy( std::begin( v1 ), std::end( v1 ), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "v2: ";
    std::copy( std::begin( v2 ), std::end( v2 ), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "v3: ";
    std::copy( std::begin( v3 ), std::end( v3 ), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto present = [&v2, &v3] ( const auto &x )
    {
        return std::find( std::begin( v2 ), std::end( v2 ), x ) != std::end( v2 ) ||
               std::find( std::begin( v3 ), std::end( v3 ), x ) != std::end( v3 );
    };

    std::cout << "\ndifference: ";
    std::remove_copy_if( std::begin( v1 ), std::end( v1 ),
                         std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ),
                         present );
    std::cout << std::endl;                         

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
v1: 0 5 7 8 9 11 
v2: 1 2 3 4 5 
v3: 3 6 7 

difference: 0 8 9 11
```

Comment: Разбираюсь, но у меня не компилируется на QT Creator.

Comment: @Trulimon Из-за чего не компилируется? Если из-за использования auto в качестве спецификатора типа в лямбда auto present = [&v2, &v3] ( const auto &x ), то замените auto на int: auto present = [&v2, &v3] ( const int &x ),

Comment: Да из-за auto, заменил всё заработало.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоватся [`copy_if`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) и [find](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    vector<int> v1 = { 0, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11 };
    vector<int> v2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector<int> v3 = { 3, 6, 7 };
    vector<int> ans;

    copy_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(ans), [v2, v3](int i) { 
      return find(v2.begin(), v2.end(), i) == v2.end() && find(v3.begin(), v3.end(), i) == v3.end();
    });

    copy(ans.begin(), ans.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    return 0;
}
```

[Код](https://repl.it/repls/YouthfulGoodnaturedWamp)

P.S. Ответ хранится в массиве `ans`